# python async sqlalchemy session get tables

Tags: python, asynchronous, sqlalchemy

how can get a list of table objects with an asynchronous session?
I tried many options but never found the right one.

This is how i get the session object itself

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import inspect
from sqlalchemy.future import select
from utils import *
import asyncio

engine = create_async_engine(config.database_url).execution_options(autocommit=True)

async_session = sessionmaker(
    engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession
)

async def execute(*args):
    return await (async_session()).execute(*args)

async def tables():
    session= async_session()
    
    #print(await session.run_sync( inspect(engine).get_table_names ))

asyncio.run(tables())
```

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#using-the-inspector-to-inspect-schema-objects

Comment: i tried this, it doesn't work with session

Answer (score 0):

```
async with engine.connect() as conn:
    tables = await conn.run_sync(
        lambda sync_conn: inspect(sync_conn).get_table_names()
    )
    print(tables)
```